# Wordpress Ultimate Member: can not see all custom fields on page when not in edit mode

Tags: wordpress

When not in edit mode I do not see all the custom fields. When you go into edit my profile I see for example the Salutation as shown in the pics below. How do I change this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i don't think the 'about' tab lets you customize what's shown on it. you'd have to code that yourself im guessing, with javascript

find the tag, insert a new line, etc etc